# Serverless AWS API conflicting routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

```
get_all_regions:
  handler: regions/admin/handler.get_all_regions
  tags:
    Name: get-all-regions
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: GET
        path: /admin/regions

get_all_regions_preflight:
  handler: default/handler.get_preflight
  tags:
    Name: get-preflight
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: OPTIONS
        path: /admin/regions

get_region:
  handler: regions/admin/handler.get_region
  tags:
    Name: get-region-details
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: GET
        path: /admin/regions/{id}

get_region_preflight:
  handler: default/handler.get_preflight
  tags:
    Name: get-preflight
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: OPTIONS
        path: /admin/regions/{id}

create_region:
  handler: regions/admin/handler.create_region
  tags:
    Name: add-region
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: POST
        path: /admin/regions
```

Error: New route /local/admin/regions conflicts with existing /local/admin/regions.

I keep getting this error despite having those routes with different method types. I have tried searching online but haven't found anything, I am trying to follow REST API conventions and hence keep it this way.

Comment: Update! I think this might be because of the preflight endpoints that I have added. still not sure though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflicting routes are the following:

```
get_region_preflight:
  handler: default/handler.get_preflight
  tags:
    Name: get-preflight
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: OPTIONS
        path: /admin/regions/{id}


get_all_regions_preflight:
  handler: default/handler.get_preflight
  tags:
    Name: get-preflight
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: OPTIONS
        path: /admin/regions
```

You're trying to deploy the same function twice, try :

```
get_regions_preflight:
  handler: default/handler.get_preflight
  tags:
    Name: get-preflight
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: OPTIONS
        path: /admin/regions
    - httpApi:
        method: OPTIONS
        path: /admin/regions/{id}
```

Comment: Yeah I found out that preflights only have to made once for a specific path. Thanks though !

Comment: If it helped, please accept the answer for future readers :)